# Data base model - CRUD on the same ENTITY by 2 service interfaces

Tags: database, architecture, model, entity

My application Model is having a particular Entity and i'm going to apply CRUD on that same Entity using 2 different service interfaces,

At the same time those 2 interfaces will work on the DB model ,I'm having this BIG design  issue that this will get me in to trouble later,

What are the problems i'm going to face by doing so,

Are there any maintenance issues arise?

Is it architecturally correct to use 2 interfaces to doing the same CRUD on same business Entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a big problem. It is actually the "Shared database" integration pattern.

The things you should watch out for are:

- It will increase your maintenence costs since you will need to update and deploy the services that use these interfaces at the same time.
- You need to be carefull that you do not introduce any locking problems, since you are accessing the data tables from 2 different directions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure at least to separate the data access (repositories) from the services, one other way is to create one data service (CRUD service), then create whatever services on top of it.